# Share Point how calculate days in whole number

Tags: calculated-column, date

I'm using this formula in shapoint to calculate the difference between start date and due date. This formula is working very well, but when the approvals receive the automatic email about the Out of Office requests via Microsoft flow, the email shows Days off field as 5,00000000 instead of 5 only. I want to see the whole number. Number of decimal places is igual to zero into the share point setttings already. Not sure how to fixed it.

```
=SUM(IF(AND((WEEKDAY([Return Date],2))<(WEEKDAY([Start Date],2)),((WEEKDAY([Start Date],2))-(WEEKDAY([Return Date],2)))>1),(((DATEDIF([Start Date],[Return Date],"D")))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Start Date],[Return Date],"D"))/7,1)*2)-2),(((DATEDIF([Start Date],[Return Date],"D")))-(FLOOR((DATEDIF([Start Date],[Return Date],"D"))/7,1)*2))),1)*1-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take care in MS flow, convert your decimal to integer or use substring function to truncate decimal places.

Below links would be useful.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/decimal-place/td-p/50303
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Flow-Discussion/Convert-text-to-number/td-p/40748
https://parserr.com/support/knowledge-base/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-microsoft-flow/

Comment: Hi, I found a simple formuma int()....inside the () we just need to include the column that we want and then it was solved...thanks for your comments.